# Row to string value in Pervasive View

Tags: pervasive-sql

I have a table as follows

```
+----------------+----------+--------+  
| purchase_order | text_seq |  text  |  
+----------------+----------+--------+  
|           1001 |        1 | screw  |  
|           1001 |        2 | m5x10  |  
|           1001 |        3 | socket |  
|           1002 |        1 | washer |  
|           1002 |        2 | m5x10  |  
+----------------+----------+--------+
```

From view need to get data as follows

```
+----------------+-------------------------+
| Purchase_order |          text           |
+----------------+-------------------------+
|           1001 | screw,m5x10,socket head |
|           1002 | washer,m5               |
+----------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Need more information.  Not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: [text as table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) is your friend.  Also, please [edit] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's not an easy way to do what you want.  If you are using a recent version of PSQL, you can create a stored procedure or function to create the "text" field in the order you want (based on text_seq I would guess) and then use that result in the overall results.
My personal preference would be to retrieve the results from the database and then format them to my needs.